# What does this symbol on the box of power supply mean?

Tags: power-supply, symbol

I always see this symbole behind electronic devices.

[image: image1]

A close-up image of the symbol:

[image: image2]

What does it mean?

Comment: You always see it?  I never see it and get really angry because it's so useful!  If I need to replace a power supply, I need that information to choose a replacement.

Comment: To me, this is the only self-explanatory icon on that power box, except the forbidden disposal. All the other 22 things mean nothing to me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Negative on the outside of the barrel connector, positive on the inside of the barrel connector.

It is the standard method of showing the polarisation of the barrel connector. The positive pin is usually (as in this case) the inner contact, and negative is usually the outside of the barrel.

If you look at the image, it shows a surrounding area labelled "-", an inner point, which it labels with a "+". Hence, negative surround, positive inner contact.

Comment: Why do they draw it on the power supply? why not near the connector?

Comment: They need the space to fit the label. As the big power supply brick has all the rest of the information, it's where people will look anyway.

Comment: And do pay attention to that symbol! While almost everything uses negative on the outside, there are some evil devices that use positive on the outside and mixing plugs probably isn't good for the devices.

Comment: @Hearth Hey, guitar pedals aren't "evil" they're just misunderstood! :)

Comment: @Roh If I have a power supply fail, I can look at the one label and get 1) Voltage  2) Amperage 3) Polarity (the symbol you are asking about).  Then I just need to know the size of the plug (there's only a few of them), and I'm able to go get a new power supply.

Comment: @JYelton: Guitar pedals supplies are almost universal, but they're all center-negative.

Comment: @supercat I know, I wasn't being literal, just borrowing a joke from the "antagonist isn't evil, just misunderstood" trope.

Comment: @JYelton: I didn't know that others would recognize that you were talking about guitar pedals because 90% of them use the same power supply configuration, but that configuration differs from what everyone else uses.

Comment: So is there any good reason for not having a standard. If most people put the + in the middle, who would decide to do it differently? Was it just  that there was no perceived standard or was there some reason specific to guitar pedals? It has always seemed logical to me to put the + in the middle, but I can't actually figure out why. I think many dry cells were centre + for practical reasons.

Comment: @roh if this were on the connector, then plug-maker would need to either make two connectors with opposite labelling (*tripling* the number of parts they need to make), or at assembly time the PSU maker needs to fit a second label in a place subject to wear and non-flat surfaces.

Answer (score 13):

To answer your comment to Puttafish,

> Why do they draw it on the power supply? Why not near the connector?

The connectors are purchased with no polarity assignment. It's up to the PSU designer what the polarity is or if it is AC. Thus it makes sense for the PSU builder to label the polarity on the PSU along with all the other technical information.

There's not a lot of room on the connectors either!

Comment: Very nice answer. How bad that we cannot mark two answers as accepted answer! Thank you